# increment variable value in function parameter

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is it possible to increment a variable's value by passing this variable to some function parameter, so that variable's value changes e.g.

```
int y=0; 
void someFunc(int a); 
somefunc(y+50); 
NSLog(@"y=@f",y); 
prints "y = 50"
```

You can do it this way

```
someFunc(y=y+50);
someFunc(y=+50);
```

but is there more elegant way accomplishing this, using pointers maybe? e.g

```
someFunc(*y+50);
```

This is the snippet of my code where I want to accomplish this

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGFloat currentX = 0;
    CGFloat currentY = height / 2;

    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 5);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);

    CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx,currentX, currentY);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, currentX=currentX+50, currentY - 200);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, currentX=+50, currentY - 200);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, currentX=+50, currentY - 200);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, currentX=+50, currentY - 200);

    CGContextDrawPath(ctx, kCGPathStroke);  
}
```

I want to keep that currentX's value being updated everytime I increment it in the function parameter. Get it?

Comment: The statement `someFunc(y=y+50);` is meaningless.  `y` is changing because you wrote an expression for the parameter.  That `someFunc()` is being called makes no difference at all.

Comment: @Avi Well, it does what he expects: taking the value as arg and adding an offset.

Comment: Passing `y=y+50` will pass the incremented value (in your example 50) to the function, not the original value.

Comment: It does what he expects, but not the way he expects.  The statement would change `y` whether or not it's passed to `someFunc()`.

Comment: Of course, but this is counting peanuts, because he does pass it to `someFunc()`. He did not say that wants an "atomic" expression. I really do not get your point.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad, he asks for a way to do this via a function, but he (and you?) miss that in his example, the function call is completely irrelevant.  The function call is not the mechanism by which `y` changes.  If the part in parentheses was executed by itself (`y=y+50`), he would get the same answer.

Comment: A `for` loop would do this better.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by passing a pointer to the variable. This is called an "out parameter" or "call by reference":

```
void someFunc( int * a, int o )
{
  …
  *a = *a + o;
}

int y = 0;
someFunc( &y, 50 );
// y is y+o
```

Comment: The function in this case is some API function which the OP cannot modify.

Answer (score 0):

Either you need to change the value before calling the function, in which case you do:

```
x = x + something;
func(x);
```

or if you need to change the value after calling the function, you do like this:

```
func(x);
x = x + something;
```

Common sense.

---

**NOTE:** *never* write code like `func(x=something)` with the assignment inside the parameter list. Because in case you get a habit of doing so, you will soon be writing order-of-evaluation bugs such as `func(x, x=something) // BAD, unspecified behavior`.

---

Alternatively, if you need to change the value *inside* the function, you could pass its address:

```
void func (int* param)
{
  *param = something;
}
...
func(&x);
```

But you can obviosuly only do this if the function is written by you. This doesn't seem to be the case here, since those functions are apparently part of some Apple library.